# git concrete commit positioning

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've several commits on dev branch. I would like to set the HEAD pointer to a concrete commit and explore my project on this commit. Right now, I want to come back to the last commit.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to return to some commit in the history, you can just use `git checkout`:

```
git checkout some-branch
git checkout or-some-tag
git checkout or-a-commit-id
```

If you check something out that is not a branch, then you will be placed onto a “detached HEAD”. That means that you are simply not on a branch currently, so any commit you may make will be lost if you switch away from it. You can always create a new branch from your current position though using `git checkout -b new-name`.

Since you only want to *explore* the repository at a certain commit, you don’t need to worry about a detached HEAD though. Just checkout that commit, and do whatever you like.

Once you are done, you can move to a different commit, or return to an actual branch, using the same command. So `git checkout dev` will put you back on the dev branch.